# Heatmaps of RNA SEQ data

Tags: r, heatmap

This is my first time in working with RNA SEQ data and I have some problems with heatmap

My data is as follows
[Data](http://www.sendspace.com/file/qoe67h)

I wanted to create a heatmap to show tissue specific expression and tried the following

```
 rownames(data)<-data$IDS
 data<-data[,-1]
 hmcol = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "GnBu"))(100)
 heatmap.2(as.matrix(data), col = hmcol, trace="none")
```

The values in the data do not match to the color key in the heatmap.Could someone please correct where am wrong?

Comment: `heatmap.2()` scales row values by default. What happens, if you specify an argument scale="none" in the call to `heatmap.2()`?

Comment: I tried that already but the heatmap was still the same.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the breaks argument? You seem to have a few extreme values, and very many zeros, which affects the automatic method for color specification. Something like this: `hmcol = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "GnBu"))(91);  heatmap.2(as.matrix(data), trace="none", breaks=as.vector(c(-0.1, quantile(as.matrix(data[data!=0]), seq(0.1,1,0.01)))), col=hmcol)` .

Comment: It improves and maybe I will work more on this for color specification. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just have *alot* of small values and few extremely large values. Hence, the color key is correct (See the histogram in the color key) but the low (grey) values just dominate the picture. You could try to plot the values on a logarithmic scale.

Maybe try something like:

```
heatmap.2(log2(as.matrix(data) + 1), col = hmcol, trace="none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you analyzed your DE? after filtration and normalization steps and finaly DE try it again on your expressed genes (also for PCA).